# Can't write to realtime firebase DB however it runs fine

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to create a new child under the iamit child that is the newly created users ID. It registers the user to Authentication however not to the realtime DB, that stays the same as it is. The hierachry is Users->iamit->userID

I cant see what's wrong, I've followed the google guidelines and it should work. I have     ".read": true,
    ".write": true in the rules.

It doesn't throw any errors and it doesn't crash when I register. It goes to the next activity and the toast saying user created with the ID shows and the user shows up in the authentication section.

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class confirmineed extends Activity {
 public static final String TAG = "TAG";
 String firstname,lastname,number,emailtxt,psw, userID;


 FirebaseAuth fAuth;
 ProgressBar progressBar;
 FirebaseFirestore fStore;
 FirebaseDatabase database;
 Button signupbtn;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirmineed);
     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     assert bundle != null;

     firstname = bundle.getString("firstname");
     lastname = bundle.getString("lastname");
     number = bundle.getString("Pnumber");
     emailtxt = bundle.getString("email");
     psw = bundle.getString("psw");


     TextView name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
     final TextView pnumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pnumber);
     TextView email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
     TextView role = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.role);
     name.setText(firstname + " " + lastname);
     pnumber.setText(number);
     email.setText(emailtxt);
     role.setText("I provide I.T. Support");


     signupbtn = findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
     fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
     fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
     database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
     progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
     progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

     signupbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {

             progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             // register the user in firebase

             fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailtxt,psw).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {

                 @Override
                 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                     if(task.isSuccessful()){
                         userID = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                         Toast.makeText(confirmineed.this, "User Created." + userID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                         DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userID);
                         Map<String,Object> user = new HashMap<>();
                         documentReference.set(user).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                             @Override
                             public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                                 String user_id = fAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                 DatabaseReference myref = database.getReference().child("Users").child("iamit").child(user_id);
                                 myref.setValue(true);

                                 Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: user Profile is created for "+ userID);

                             }
                         }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                             @Override
                             public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                 Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.toString());
                             }
                         });
                         startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),iamitlogin.class));

                     }else {
                         Toast.makeText(confirmineed.this, "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     }
                 }
             });
         }


     });


 }


 public void onBackPressed(View view){
     Intent sendback = new Intent(this, signupend.class);
     sendback.putExtra("firstname", firstname);
     sendback.putExtra("lastname", lastname);
     sendback.putExtra("Pnumber", number);
     sendback.putExtra("email", emailtxt);
     sendback.putExtra("psw", psw);
     startActivity(sendback);
     overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
 };


}
```

Comment: FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();    DatabaseReference dbRef = database.getReference();       dbRef = database.getReference("/test/data/message1");     dbRef.setValue("Hello");

Comment: Try this for writing in database

Comment: That doesn't do anything. Just the same as always.

Comment: Check your connectivity to firebase

Comment: It says its all connected and it still adds new users to the authentication when registering.

Comment: What is your rulls of realtime database?  See realtime database page of your app to check any node is created or not

Comment: "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }

Comment: no nodes are being created

Comment: In your realtime database of Firebase, you haven't anything?

Comment: Go to tools>firebase>realtime database in Android Studio and check connections.

Comment: It has the main node and nothing underneath that.

Comment: connected and all dependencies are set correctly

Comment: What does it mean in your code? myref.setValue(true)

Comment: You want to save "true" word?

Comment: the reason for that being there is so that the UserID is actually written to the DB. I read that without that the data will not be written . true is just the bool value to make sure the function runs

Comment: So, you haven't written anything in database, you just have pointed to its childs

Comment: ah okay, however If I put the variable user_id it still doesn't get saved

Comment: Try something like myref.setValue("true") and check Firebase

Comment: still nothing, it still adds the user to authentication but doesn't add to the DB#

Comment: Put (DatabaseReference myref = database.getReference().child("Users").child("iamit").child(user_id); myref.setValue("true");) out of successlistener. You put it in read section.

Comment: that fixed it :D Thank you very much

Comment: Your welcome, you can check my answer as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `DatabaseReference myref = database.getReference().child("Users").child("iamit").child(user_id); myref.setValue("true");` out of successlistener. You put it in read section